# Dynamic HTML table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table where users can add rows to dynamically.  One of the fields, my date field, must be the same for all rows that are added.  I have made the date field clone on all additional rows, and made that field read-only on created rows, but I'm wondering if there is a way that I can add some code in there that if the user goes back to the first row and changes the date of the receipt, then all rows that were added by the user will also update to the new date.

```
<table border="0" width="825px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" name="receipts" id = "receipts">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="colheader" width="125px">Receipt #</th>
        <th class="colheader" width="120px">Date</th>
        <th class="colheader" width="120px">Category</th>
        <th class="colheader" width="120px">Description</th>
        <th class="colheader" width="120px">Amount</th>
        <th class="colheader" width="145px"><span class="boldblacklinks"><a href="#" id="add">[Add +]</a></span></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody class="lineBdy">
        <tr id="line_1" class="spacer">
            <td><input type="text" class="receipt fieldclasssm" id="recLineReceipt[]" name="recLineReceipt[]" size="7" value = "<?=$receiptNumber?>"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="date fieldclasssm" id="recLineDate[]" name="recLineDate[]" size="10" value = "<?=date("m/d/Y", strtotime($today))?>"/></td>
            <td><select name="selectCategory[]" class="fieldclasssm">
                        <option value = "">Select a Category...</option>
                        <?php //Get Categories

                        $getCats = mysql_query("SELECT id, nominalName FROM expense_nominalCodes ORDER BY id") or die("Get Cats: " . mysql_error());

                        if(mysql_num_rows($getCats) > 0)
                            {
                            while($catData = mysql_fetch_array($getCats))
                                {
                                echo '<option value = "'.$catData['id'].'">'.$catData['nominalName'] . '</option>';
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="lineDescr fieldclasssm" name="recLineDescr[]" id="recLineDescr[]" value = "<?=$_POST['recLineDescr']?>" size="40" /></td>
            <td colspan = "2"><input type="text" class="amt fieldclasssm" name="recLineAmount[]" id="recLineAmount[]" value = "<?=$_POST['recLineAmount']?>" size="12" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div align="center"><br /><br /><input type="submit" name = "saveAdd" class="btn" value = "Save & Add Another Receipt" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name = "saveAdd" class="btn" value = "Save as Draft" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" class="btn"name="saveDraft" value = "Save & Finalize Expense Report" /><br /><br /></div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Add new table row & clone date field
$('#add').on('click', function(){
   addReceiptItem();
    $('.date').focus(function() {
        $(this).select();
    });
    $('.receipt').focus(function() {
        $(this).select();
    }); 
});

function addReceiptItem(){
     var lastID = $('tr[id*="line_"]').length,    
         newTds = $('tr[id="line_' + lastID + '"] td').clone(),
         newRow = document.createElement('tr');

    // add new id and class to row, append cloned tds
    $(newRow)
        .attr('id', 'line_' + (lastID + 1 ))
        .attr('class', 'spacer')
        .append(newTds);

    //empty out the fields, except the one you want to keep populated
    // $(newRow).find('input').not(':eq(0)').val('');

     // $(newRow).find('input').not(':eq(0)').val('');


    $(newRow).find('input').not(':eq(0)').not(':eq(0)').val('');
    $(newRow).find('class').not(':eq(0)').not(':eq(0)').val('');

    //add the new row to the table body
    $('tbody.lineBdy').append(newRow);
    $('.receipt').attr('readonly', true);
    $('.date').attr('readonly', true);
    };
```

Comment: Just a thought, dynamically added rows could contain a custom data attribute (`data-added`), if a row has this and the user changes the date, update these rows.

Comment: Do you have sample code to get me started?  I'm far too new with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those fields all have the `date` class you can call something like

```
$('#someUpdateButton').click(function(){
  $('.date').val($('.date:nth-of-type(1)').val())
});
```

[A working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFBcZ/3/)

Comment: Would it be possible to do this once the new date is selected without having to press an update button?

Comment: @Dan Yeah you can use any event handler. Button click was just the fastest one for me to type up. Are you looking to do like as you type out the date?

Comment: I'm using the jQuery datepicker to generate the date.